# Is this function injective or surjective?

Tags: functions

The given function F : P(A) --> A so that F(B)⋲B for any nonempty B ⊆ A

Is it necessarily injective (one-to-one) or surjective (onto)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint.** It is not necessarily injective.  See if you can prove this by finding a counterexample: Define a function $F$ such that two subsets $B_1, B_2$ both map onto the same element of $A$.

It is necessarily surjective.  See if you can prove this by finding, for any element $a \in A$, a subset $B \subseteq A$ such that $F(B) = a$ is forced.

Answer (score 0):

No function $P(A) \to A$ can be injective because of Cantor's theorem.

As to whether $F$ is surjective, consider singletons $B$.